# vue-router why when I refresh a page that has a URL contains id, I lose all design of page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vuex, vue-router

I am a redirect from the target component to target-details component using specific id, so my issue is when I refresh a page I am getting an error `javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     app.js:1`.
and after click back button of the browser or redirect to another page then a design came back again
I don't know what is going on, and all my other pages are working correctly.

index.html

```html
<head>
    <meta name="author" content="Nile-Theme">
    <meta name="robots" content="index follow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index follow">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700|Tajawal:400,500,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/style.css">

    <!-- main dashboard -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/now-ui-dashboard.css') }}">

    <!-- Nprogress -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.js"></script>



</head>

<body >
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but full-hunt doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

    <!-- js file -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="./build/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

target.js

```js
<template>
   <div class="page-output">
        <div class="container">

           <h1>Target page</h1>
 <li class="clearfix" v-for="domain in domains" :key="domain.domain_id">{{ domain.domain }} 
                            <router-link class="more" 
                                :to="{ 
                                        name: 'target-details', 
                                        params: { 
                                            id: domain.domain_id 
                                        } 
                                    }" >Target details <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </router-link>
                        </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

target-details.js

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="page-output">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="target-title">
                    <router-link class="right" to="/targets"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> {{ geNameDomainById(id) }} domain</router-link>
                    <a href="#" class="left"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Domain settings</a>
                </div>
           </div> 
        </div>
</template>
```

router.js

```js
 {
        path: '/targets',
        name: 'target',
        component: () =>
            import ( /* webpackChunkName: "target" */ '@/views/admin/Target.vue'),
            meta: {
                middleware: [
                    auth
                ],
                title: "Targets"
            },
    },
    {
        path: '/targets/:id/details',
        name: 'target-details',
        component: () =>
            import ( /* webpackChunkName: "target" */ '@/views/admin/TargetDetails.vue'),
            meta: {
                middleware: [
                    auth
                ],
                title: "TargetDetails"
            }
    },
```

Comment: when you refresh, your browser is trying to load `./build/js/app.js` - which is relative to the path in the address ... e.g. when the address is `//host/targets` the browser is loading `//host/targets/./build/js/app.js` ... whereas when the address is `//host/targets/111/details` the browser tries to load `//host/targets/111/details/./build/js/app.js` - which of course won't exists. So the server sends an error page, whose first character is probably `<`

Comment: @Jaromanda X so what should I do in this case

Comment: Sorry, that I don't know - I've never added an arbitrary js file like that in any vue app I've ever made - perhaps make ALL the paths to `./build/....` absolute, like `/build/...` instead

Comment: can u show us your style css file? @Omda

Comment: @Jenuel [this](https://textuploader.com/16akm) my style.css

Comment: @Jaromanda X , I tried to use helper function ```mix``` to a refrence to the absolute path but it doesn't load my styles and js files, I don't know why ```mix``` helper doesn't work, If you can, could you tell me how you are reference to your the absolute path of your vue js project as you said you never use what I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the absolute path for all your JavaScript and Stylesheets.

Ex. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/build/js/app.js"></script>`

You also have extra `}}` characters in your `now-ui-dashboard.css` link tag.

Comment: thanks to a reply, yah I fixed what you said, but nothing happen yet

Comment: it's work after I review my header tag then I remove dot at the beginning of the path for every file ```./build/app.js ```to ```/build/app.js``` as you said and then its work. thanks a lot